How does one characterize the complexity of possible realities?
Let’s say you are to evaluate the proposition that God created the universe. Let’s call this proposition A.
Let’s now say you are to evaluate the proposition that a SuperGod created God who then created the universe. Let’s call this proposition B.
It seems intuitive that proposition B is less likely than proposition A given Occam’s razor, even if we can’t accurately define what “likely” even means here. Proposition B “includes” proposition A.
But what if proposition B was: A super devil created a devil god (who has all the attributes that God does except He’s evil) who then created the universe? In this case, proposition B doesn’t directly include proposition A yet it may seem intuitively more complex than A. Why should this intuition be any less accurate than the first one?
In general, how should one in their heads assign belief to these different imagined realities? Should they presume a complete lack of knowledge given no access to these realities and thus be in a suspended belief state or can one still make judgements on the possibilities of these realities perhaps through intuition or some apriori principle? Is there any philosophical literature specifically targeted towards this concept?
I can see answers both ways but one argument I can think of against complete belief suspension is that almost all of us don’t just have a suspended belief in certain magical beings such as Santa Claus even if we can’t disprove it. We actively disbelieve in Santa Claus, or Harry Potter style magic, etc. Why should we then have suspended beliefs to the kinds of realities that I just mentioned?

I don't see the point in discussing a belief in this abstract way as though bare plausibility were the reason anyone decides whether or not to believe it. There are lots of reasons, both rational and irrational to believe in God or disbelieve in God. Any attempt say whether a belief is rational or justified without taking those reasons into account is unlikely to lead to any useful conclusions.

On the standard monotheistic conception of God as the ultimate source of being, the idea of SuperGod is incoherent and the likelihood of proposition B is zero. Such a created "God" cannot have "all the attributes that God does" regardless of whether he is good or evil. The idea of evil creator (not a true God) was endorsed in one of Christian heresies, gnosticism, but probabilities and Occam's razor play no role in theological discussions of heresies either.

@Conifold the question is not about whether certain realities fit to certain pre existing models, in this case theistic models. The question is about how, if even possible, to evaluate the complexities and plausibilities of certain theories in as close to an objective way as possible. Just assume that SuperGod is the monotheistic god and that God is what SuperGod uses as proxy to create things and purposefully obfuscates mention of in scripture. What strength of belief should you now have in this proposition?

If the basis of evaluation is supposed to be 'intuitions' about simplicity then objective way is a lost cause. And if  existing discourses are beside the point then complexities and plausibilities of idle speculations seem of little value on top of it. We can think up a lot of things, there has to be a compelling reason to bother with any one of them.

@Conifold Compelling to who? You? Or most people? And if most people, are you saying that intuition is a lost cause unless there is a compelling reason which is itself based on intuition? Is there anything not based on intuition?

Please identify the accounts you previously posted under. Thx


can one still make judgements on the possibilities of these realities perhaps through intuition or some apriori principle?

No. In general there is insufficient evidence in theology to tell whether any god was created by a previous god or not, or even if any god is eternal in the time of this universe or whatever timeline they are in. In theology this is a matter of revelation, not deductions (though sometimes things need to be deducted from revelation, but those still end up being justified by revelation).
Conifold said in the arguments that

On the standard monotheistic conception of God as the ultimate source of being, the idea of SuperGod is incoherent

But I see no reason to restrict ourselves to whatever "standard" that is supposed to be, unless the question specifically refers to any such conception. Certainly Christian theologies tried to add all kinds of shit to revelations of their scriptures to firm such a standard, but they disagree with each other enough to have plenty of leeway. Such as Jesus being a god that has been created by a super god in a dodgy menage-a-trois with underage Mary.

is less likely...

There is also no quantitative comparation possible in general when comparing theories that way. That is mere conjecture of Occam's razor.
Rather, the problem is that all theories involving even more gods than one are equally lacking enough evidence, and for any two people to agree on anything, the model with the least things to disagree about is most useful.

Well, 'suspended belief' argument is an attempt to shift the burden of proof. It's not the skeptic's job to disprove every conceivable supernatural claim. It's the believer's job to provide evidence for their specific claim. Until such evidence is forthcoming, skepticism is the only rational position.
As for Santa Claus or Harry Potter we don't 'suspend belief' in these fictional characters because there's no compelling reason to believe in them. The same principle applies to gods, devils, and all manner of supernatural beings. What you call "Active disbelief" is just the default position in the absence of evidence.
We don't need elaborate philosophical frameworks to justify our lack of belief in the unbelievable. We simply require evidence, and in the case of the supernatural, it's absent, that's all.
